# debugging Android UDP listening

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp

I want to get in my `Android` emulator  some incoming data sent by remote computer on my local network. So first,

```
InetAddress[] inetAddress = InetAddress.getAllByName(android_emulator_ip);
s = new DatagramSocket();
s.connect(inetAddress[0], some_udp_port);
```

I got the `android_emulator_ip` running `adb shell;ifconfig eth0`. This `IP` is the one used by the remote computer.

The weird thing is that if I change this `ip` to a random one, I get in my break point debugger for the DatagramSocket object, the value  `isConnected =true`

By the way, I can't catch any error in the following. If I log after `s.receive(p);` in the following `try` block, it seems not to be read

```
byte[] message = new byte[300];
DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message,message.length);
try{
    s.receive(p);
 }catch{...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it debugged setting a timeout this way

```
s = new DatagramSocket(some_udp_port);
s.setSoTimeout(3000);
```

and then this worked

```
byte[] message = new byte[256];
DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message,message.length);
try{
    s.receive(p);
}
```

The issue was related to use `connect`and so to put the emulator in a position of server rather than listener